# Create dyadic (relational) data from monadic data

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I have conflict data that looks like this

```
conflict_ID country_code   SideA
1              1             1          
1              2             1 
1              3             0
2              4             1
2              5             0
```

Now I want to make it into dyadic conflict data that looks like this (SideA=1 should be `country_code_1`):

```
conflict_ID country_code_1 country_code_2 
1              1             3          
1              2             3 
2              4             5
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a direct approach:

```
df %>%
  filter(SideA == 1) %>%
  select(conflict_ID, country_code_1 = country_code) %>%
  left_join(
    df %>%
      filter(SideA == 0) %>%
      select(conflict_ID, country_code_2 = country_code),
    by = "conflict_ID"
  )
#   conflict_ID country_code_1 country_code_2
# 1           1              1              3
# 2           1              2              3
# 3           2              4              5
```

Using this data:

```
df = read.table(text = 'conflict_ID country_code   SideA
1              1             1          
1              2             1 
1              3             0
2              4             1
2              5             0 ', header = T)
```

Comment: This works! It does not produce the problem the first solution does.

Answer (score 1):

This extends the [previous issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73712096/10068985) you posted. You could produce all combinations for each `conflict_ID`, and filter out those combinations where `country_code_2` matches `country_code` with `SideA == 1`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf %>%
  group_by(conflict_ID) %>%
  summarise(country_code = combn(country_code, 2, sort, simplify = FALSE),
            .groups = 'drop') %>%
  unnest_wider(country_code, names_sep = '_') %>%
  anti_join(filter(mydf, SideA == 1),
            by = c("conflict_ID", "country_code_2" = "country_code"))

# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#   conflict_ID country_code_1 country_code_2
#         <int>          <int>          <int>
# 1           1              1              3
# 2           1              2              3
# 3           2              4              5
```

Comment: ````error: Join columns must be present in data.
x Problem with `country_code_2`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
Join columns must be present in data.
x Problem with `country_code_2`.
Backtrace:
 1. `%>%`(...)
 3. dplyr:::anti_join.data.frame(...)
 4. dplyr:::join_filter(x, y, by = by, type = "anti", na_matches = na_matches)
 5. dplyr:::join_cols(tbl_vars(x), tbl_vars(y), by = by)
 6. dplyr:::standardise_join_by(by, x_names = x_names, y_names = y_names)
 7. dplyr:::check_join_vars(by$x, x_names)````

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I get the error posted above. Any ideas?

Comment: @craszer you mess up the column names. What's your code?

Comment: my code is:

```
MIDdyadic <- MID2014 %>%
  group_by(dispnum) %>%
  summarise(iso3 = combn(iso3, 2, sort, simplify = FALSE),
            .groups = 'drop') %>%
  unnest_wider(iso3, names_sep = '_') %>%
  anti_join(filter(MID2014, sidea == 1),
            by = c("dispnum", "iso3nr2" = "iso3"))
```

all column names are actual column names from the data, except vor "iso3nr2" which is not an actual column (corresponding to your code, right?)

Comment: @craszer `anti_join(filter(MID2014, sidea == 1), by = c("dispnum", "iso3_2" = "iso3"))`

Comment: Upon detailed inspection I noticed that not all dispute pairs are listed in the new table. They only appear, if in the original table, SideA was the first country in the list (table showed 1) and in the next row, the other party had a 0 (indicating that they are not SideA). If it is the other way around, the dyad simply doesnt show up in the table that is created. Any ideas of why that might be?